# Constraining an SQL search query by aspx membership

Tags: sql-server-2008, asp.net-membership

I am working on a class project.  I have a database that collects info from the user and stores it.  I want to display the data each user adds to the database in an aspx grid view.  I started to create a search query, but I don't know how to constrain the results to just one user.

SelectCommand =

`SELECT * FROM` ( NEED ) `WHERE` ( This is the part I am trying to figure out )
`Username = Membership.GetUser()`

(NEED is the table where I am getting data from, Username is the value I want to search by, and Membership.GetUser() is the user name of the person logged in)

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little vague but as I understand it - you want to obtain the properties associated with a user's profile by way of their username.  Depending on the setup and version of your aspx membership provider it will likely be something like this:

```
select aspnet_Profile.* 
    from aspnet_Profile inner join aspnet_Users
       on aspnet_Profile.UserId = aspnet_Users.UserId 
    where aspnet_Users.UserName = @Username
```

This assumes that you are using the membership profile objects to store user related data.  This would seem logical but many applications extend, modify, or completely build their own data stores to relate to aspx membership users.

Comment: Thanks - after I posted it I realized that I could use a label that I had assigned the user name value to.

SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [NEED] WHERE ([Username] = @Username)

Comment: OK, modified my answer a little then